# ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, cmake

After I updated my Mac to Big Sur, I made a mistake that deleted my old python version. I tried to install python3.7 by homebrew, but meet many problems with pip.

For example, I use pip to install pandas, but it takes a really long time to "Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517)". And when I use pip to install opencv-python, I get error like: "ERROR: Could not build wheels for cmake which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly".

In the past, I never care PEP 517 and cmake, but now they trouble me so much.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrhuS.png

Comment: If you are not familiar with these. I suggest your just use Anaconda. It would save your time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an expert in cmake, but I found that it was sufficient to:

```
pip install cmake
```

or perhaps

```
python3 -m pip install -U cmake
```

(I didn't try the latter, since the first was sufficient to get opencv-python to install...)  HTH.